# What is the correct way to filter a &[&str]?

Tags: rust

I am trying to filter an array of type `&[&str]` in the following way, in able to exclude the " " case:

```
let example_array : &[&str] = &["hello", " ", "world"]; 
let filtered_array : &[&str] = example_array.iter().copied().filter(|&word| word != " ").collect();
```

The error I get is:

##### value of type `&[&str]` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`

Could someone explain why is not working, and where to look for solution?

Comment: You need to collect it into `Vec<&str>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman is it possible to collect it into an array?

Comment: An array, yes, but not with std only. A slice, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&[&str]` is a reference to a slice (array) of string references. This works with your static array of strings because the compiler is able to put it into a static data section and create a reference to it. The `collect` function cannot return a `&[&str]`, but it can return a dynamically allocated `Vec<&str>`

```
let example_array: &[&str] = &["hello", " ", "world"];
let filtered_array: Vec<&str> = example_array.iter().copied().filter(|&word| word != " ").collect();
```

**EDIT:**

`Vec<&str>` implements `Deref<Target = [&str]>`, meaning you can use a `Vec<&str>` as a `&[&str]` by taking a reference to it.

```
let filtered_array_ref: &[&str] = &filtered_array;
```